# Accessing browser objects within a module using JSDom

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jsdom

**Context:**

Using JSDom, I am trying to create a helper to define unit tests for frontend side in a simple and straightforward way. The helper lets to define an HTML context and then add a function to be interpreted as a browser code although it is executed on the NodeJS runtime environment. Following is a code example using the helper for this purpose:

```js
    // Test.js

    import Events from 'Events.js'

    let Test = THelper (`
      <div>
        <div X>X</div>
        <div Y>Y</div>
      </div>
    `)

     Test (async function (Events) {
       // this is browser code
       let NX = document.querySelector ('[X]')
       let NY = document.querySelector ('[Y]')
       let EX = Events (NX)  // [1] Error!
       let EY = Events (NY)
       EX.fire ('X')
       EY.fire ('Y')
     }

     // Events.js

     export default function Events (node) {
       function fire (type, context) {
         let ctx   = { detail: context }
         let event = new CustomEvent (type, ctx) // [1] Error!
         node.dispatchEvent (event)
       }
     }
```

**Solution:**

In order to get this behavior I have implemented the following solution. The helper transforms the testing function into a valid string code to be executed as an embedded script by JSDom. The beforeParse method is used to transfer actual parameters to the testing function using `window` as a supporting object:

```js
    function THelper (html) {
      function asScript (fn) {
        return `
          <script>
            (async function () {
              let fn  = ${fn.toString ()}
              let out = await fn (...args)
              window.result = out
            })()
          </script>
        `
      }
      return async function (fn, ...args) {
        let Cfg  = CONFIG
        let code = html + asScript (fn)
        let Dom  = new JSDOM (code, { ...Cfg,
          beforeParse (window) {
            window.args = args
          }
        })
      }
    }
```

**Problem:**

This solution works properly in general terms but when it is imported, from the NodeJS context, a module referring to a browser object, an error is thrown. This is my case in the breakpoints marked as [1]. It seems in fact that within the `fire` function the `global` object is present instead of `window`.

I can understand that this is the proper behavior. After all, the `Event.js` module is loaded by the NodeJS environment where browser objects do not exist. But, then this is my question:

**How can I get a testing environment able to execute unit tests on the JSDom virtual browser by importing "external" modules such as `Event.js` referring browser objects?**